# Variant application and user (running application) permissions requirements - Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, permissions, users, application

What is the best way to have users run an application, on Windows Server 2003, referencing a configuration file without the users having permissions to read that configuration file?  Any username and password with permission to view and/or edit the configuration file cannot be accessible to the users.

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Answer (score 1):

If the application is running in the context of the user and needs read access to the configuration file, there's no way to restrict the user from opening that file directly.  It's just not possible.  The user's account either has read access or it doesn't.  The only way around this is to run the application in the context of another user.

It might be possible to give read access to the computer's account and have the application run in the SYSTEM context.  Though, depending on the type of application, you may deem that to be a security risk.